# How does my project not complain about unresolved undependecies unless prompted?

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" int calcSum_(int a, int b, int c);

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
    return 1;
}
```

Why does the following code build granted that I have no other source files in my project with a calcSum_ function inside them? It does complain when I try to do the following:

```
int result = calcSum_(1,2,3);
```

Doesn't building involve creating an executable file which can run? Doesn't this involve linking? How can it build without errors? Why do I need to "highlight" to my linker that the function is missing?

Comment: If you never call the function, why should the linker bother to go look for it?

Comment: Uh, maybe because `calcSum_() != calcSum()` (notice the underscore)?

Comment: @paulsm4 my bad. I edited adding the underscore

Comment: Sometimes the line line between the linker and the compiler is a bit blurred at the front end. If your project is simple or fully specified the compiler can call the linker for you and just get 'er done in one step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Traditionally speaking, the linker does a pretty low level job. Object files contains a list of exported symbols (along with their address) and a list of missing symbols (along with the addresses where the resolved address must be replaced inside the code). The linker has to take them all together, find the missing symbols in the other object files and do the replacements.

Now, if the compiler sees a function prototype but it isn't used, the information is not passed along to the linker - the object file does not need that symbol, no replacement has to take place -, so the linker has no way of knowing that some function was declared but not defined.

Incidentally, this behavior was actively exploited in some C++03 idioms - in particular, the "disabled copy constructor"; you declared the copy constructor to disable the automatically generated one, but you didn't implement it, so that a linking error was emitted in case someone accidentally tried to use it.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, if someone tried to use the copy constructor then the linker would complain? (to prevent accidental use of the copy constructor?

Comment: @Bula: exactly (although, this was a second line of protection, the first level being declaring such non-implemented constructor as private, which gives better feedback on the location of erroneous usage; the linking part was to avoid the accidental use by the class itself).

Comment: any way to force the implementation of such functions? I assume a checker function to call and not save the return of such functions?

Comment: It would work, but it's a bit of a chore (you have to prepare fake arguments and the like); instead, you can make a global non-static `void *` array initialized with the pointers to such functions. That would force the reference to them to be included without needing to actually call them.

Answer (score 1):

In the program you provided, symbol `calcSum_` is never referenced, so it is never output by the compiler into your Object (`.o` or `.obj`) file.   The program's ONLY dependency is on function `printf` (from the C standard runtime libraries)

When the linker is run, it works to link symbols in the Object files. 
The symbol `calcSum_` is not in the object file, so the linker does not need to link it, and you have a successfully built executable.

Comment: Maybe very noobish question, but it starts working out the symbols that it needs to link starting from the main function down to its return value?

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
extern "C" int calcSum_(int a, int b, int c);
```

Tells the compiler that a function exists and how to call it.  Nothing more, nothing less.

If you call the function, then the *linking* phase will need to find it.

In your first example, there is no calling of the function, so there is no need for the linker to use it.  This is one of the benefits of the C++ language, you don't pay for what you don't use.

In the second example, you call the function, so it must exist.

Comment: I was thinking of Java interfaces which require you to implement the functions defined inside them. So if I understand correctly, linking only happens between things that you call inside the code? You can have 20 unimplemented functions? On a totally different note, how would you force an error if the functions are not implemented? (even if not called)